# Pdf sync with TeXShop

Tags: texshop, forward-inverse-search

I am using TexShop on a Mac OS X Lion. I can sync between the `pdf` file and the `tex` file by a right click on "Sync" on the mouse.

My question is the following:

Is it possible also when I compile a `tex` file (by pressing "Typeset") to get the `pdf` file opened exactly at the corresponding string (or page) which I just wrote in the `tex` file?

Should I change anything in the LaTeX settings in order to get this feature?

Comment: You can simply hold down the Command key (⌘) and left-click on a word in the source code (`.tex` file) and the PDF viewer will jump right to the corresponding paragraph as well as highlight it. This works in both directions, this means you can Command-click a word in the PDF and it will jump to the position in your source code.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no. While you can jump from the source to the output in the PDF (as commented, using Command key (⌘) and left-click), this won't happen automatically when you compile.